# How to successfully write & run a SQL query in Python script which is built in Elasticsearch Kibana?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

I have been trying to implement the SQL query in a python script that is working in ES Kibana but when I run it, I'm facing errors.

Following query working in Kibana

```
POST _opendistro/_sql?format=json
{
  "query": "select * from test_index where ['title_name.S'] like 'iron%' limit 10"
}
```

Following is the snippet of the function that I've been using in the Python script.

```
def sql(index):
    response = es.search(
        body ={
                "query":  "select * from " + index + " limit 10"
            }
        )
    return response
```

Following is the error that I get when I try to run the script.

[image]

Is there an alternative way to resolve or fix this issue?
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

assuming you're using the [elasticsearch-py](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/6.8.2/) Python client, it seems you're using the [search API](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/6.8.2/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.search), which issues GET requests to the `_search` endpoint of an index. What you want to send instead is a POST request to the `_opendistro/_sql` endpoint. You won't find an API for that in the Python client, but you can use e.g. the Python `requests` library to issue any HTTP request.